# Как проверить данные на однородность?

Tags: postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пик в центре - некорректные данные. Каким образом можно найти такие моменты?

То есть каким sql запросом можно получить ид записи с ложными данными при условии, если известно что разница не может быть больше какого-нибудь числа

Comment: взять производную и взять все, что отличается от нуля больше, чем на погрешность.

Answer (score -1):

1. Сформулировать правила неоднородности (некорректности)
2. Проверять данные по этому правилу
3. Выбрать что делать с некорректными данными
4. Сделать это